# Match same string as single or composed word and remove duplicates

Tags: regex, awk, sed

I have a text file with lines like this

```
Chi Allegati N.22021.htm
Casabella Marzo 2021.pdf
Casabella Febbraio 2021.pdf
Chi 24 Febbraio 2021.pdf
Chi Allegati N.22021.pdf
Casa Facile Febbraio 2021.pdf
Caccia Magazine Dicembre 2020.pdf
Chi N 1003 Marzo 2021.pdf
Chi 10 Marzo 2021.pdf
Chi N 1110 Marzo 2021_2.pdf
Casa Facile Marzo 2021.pdf
Chi 10 Febbraio 2021_2.pdf
Casa Facile Febbraio 2021_2.pdf
Chi 27 Gennaio 2021.pdf
Chi 10 Febbraio 2021.pdf
Casa Naturale Marzo Aprile 2021.pdf
Chi 31 Marzo 2021.pdf
Caccia Magazine Ottobre 2020.pdf
Chi 3 Marzo 2021.pdf
```

**Desire output**: I try to get this list

```
Casa Facile
Caccia Magazine
Casa Naturale
Casabella
Chi
Chi Allegati
Chi N
```

I use this regex but is insufficient

Find what: `^((?:\w+\h+){1,2})(.*)$\R\1.*`
Replace with: `$1`

I don't know if is sufficient a regex or if here is needed awk, sed. So I add tags for this reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `sed` could you please try following, written and tested with your shown samples in GNU `sed`.

```
sed -E 's/(^[a-zA-Z]+)([[:space:]]+[a-zA-Z]+)?([[:space:]]+[a-zA-Z]+)?.*/\1\2/' Input_file | sort -u
```

***OR***

```
sed -E 's/(^[a-zA-Z]+)([[:space:]]+[a-zA-Z]+){0,1}.*/\1\2/' Input_file | sort -u
```

---

---

***EDIT:*** AS per OP's comment `sort -u` command is not working for OP in OP's environment, so adding following code which has worked for OP.

```
sed -E 's/(^[a-zA-Z]+)([[:space:]]+[a-zA-Z]+){0,1}.*/\1\2/' file1.txt | sort | uniq
```

Comment: Thank you, under linux works correctly. I try to use it under windows  in this way `sed -E "s/(^[a-zA-Z]+)([[:space:]]+[a-zA-Z]+)?([[:space:]]+[a-zA-Z]+)?.*/\1\2/" file.txt | sort -u` but it return me this error **-uThe system cannot find the file specified.
sed: couldn't flush stdout: Invalid argument**

Comment: @AlexDoc, yeah may be that option is not present in your sed. Both worked fine with my Linux system

Comment: yes, under linux it works fine also for me but not under windows.

Comment: @AlexDoc, sorry I don't have sed on windows , are you using cygwin to run these commands?

Comment: @AlexDoc if the goal is to run under Windows what about to add the tag in your question ?

Comment: @AlexDoc, try something like `sed -E 's/(^[a-zA-Z]+)([[:space:]]+[a-zA-Z]+){0,1}.*/\1\2/' file1 | sort | uniq` once? Actually `sort -u` is shortcut of `sort | uniq` so lets try to run them in different and check if it works?

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 if this is not the option `-u` it is about the fact there is no input for *sort*, so the *pipe* does not work, in that case produce the result of *sed* in a file, then get that temp file as the input of *sort* ?

Comment: @bruno, yeah, in case output is coming from somewhere else to `sed` then pipe could be used in place of passing filenme to `sed` and then further pipe could be used with sort and uniq(shown in my previous comment) to get it done sir.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 i was used GnuWin32 (awk, sed, grep..), ok, I try to use cygwin follow your code `sed -E 's/(^[a-zA-Z]+)([[:space:]]+[a-zA-Z]+){0,1}.*/\1\2/' file1.txt | sort | uniq > zz.txt` and it works correctly. Thanks. But using GnuWin seems broken like

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 I try to test your solution to another list but it fails. Can you take a look, please? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66948698/sed-awk-removing-duplicates-interpreted-according-to-a-pattern-fails

Comment: @AlexDoc, Thanks for opening new question. This solution is for this question's data set, looks like other question's dataset is different so solution could be changed. I will check that question in sometime and will comment on there, cheers

Answer (score 3):

Here is an `awk`: solution:

```sh
awk 'match($0, /^[a-zA-Z]+( +[a-zA-Z]+)?/) {unq[substr($0, 1, RLENGTH)]} END {for (i in unq) print i}' file.txt

Caccia Magazine
Casabella Febbraio
Casabella Marzo
Casa Naturale
Casa Facile
Chi Allegati
Chi N
Chi
```

---

*Alternatively* there is a `grep + sort -u` solution:

```sh
grep -Eo '^[a-zA-Z]+( +[a-zA-Z]+)?' file.txt | sort -u

Caccia Magazine
Casa Facile
Casa Naturale
Casabella Febbraio
Casabella Marzo
Chi
Chi Allegati
Chi N
```

Comment: I tried to use under windows but it do no nothing. I replace `'` into `"` but nothing. I replace file with file.txt. In grep, under windows, I get this error **-uThe system cannot find the file specified.
grep: write error: Invalid argument**

Comment: Even if file has DOS line break. both `awk` and `grep` solutions should work fine. What is your awk version?

Comment: I download awk from here. http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/gawk.htm - I test your code but doesn't work under windows

Comment: Try this: `awk 'match($0, /^[a-zA-Z]+( +[a-zA-Z]+)?/) {unq[substr($0, 1, RLENGTH)]} END {for (i in unq) print i}' file.txt`

Comment: yes, it works perfectly now, I use this `awk "match($0, /^[a-zA-Z]+( +[a-zA-Z]+)?/) {unq[substr($0, 1, RLENGTH)]} END {for (i in unq) print i}" file.txt > ZZ.txt` - thank you very much

Comment: I try to test your solution to another list but it fails. Can you take a look, please? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66948698/sed-awk-removing-duplicates-interpreted-according-to-a-pattern-fails

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E 's/\s+\S+\s+[0-9]\S+$|[0-9].*//;s/(\S+\s+\S+)\s+\S+$/\1/
        H;x;s/((\n[^\n]*)(\n[^\n]*)*)\2$/\1/;x;$!d;x;s/.//' file
```

Manipulate the line to contain only the fields required.

Append to the hold space.

Swap to the hold space, remove duplicate lines and swap back to the pattern space.

Delete all but the last line.

On the last line, swap to the hold space, remove the first newline and print the results.

Comment: I try to test your solution to another list but it fails. Can you take a look, please? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66948698/sed-awk-removing-duplicates-interpreted-according-to-a-pattern-fails