# Removing duplicates interpreted according to a pattern, fails

Tags: awk, sed

I have some problems with these awk-sed scripts

```
sed -E 's/(^[a-zA-Z]+)([[:space:]]+[a-zA-Z]+){0,1}.*/\1\2/' file1.txt | sort | uniq > zz.txt
```

or other equivalent (windows GNU)

```
awk "match($0, /^[a-zA-Z]+( +[a-zA-Z]+)?/) {unq[substr($0, 1, RLENGTH)]} END {for (i in unq) print i}" file.txt > ZZ.txt
```

or another for linux is

```
sed -E 's/\s+\S+\s+[0-9]\S+$|[0-9].*//;s/(\S+\s+\S+)\s+\S+$/\1/
        H;x;s/((\n[^\n]*)(\n[^\n]*)*)\2$/\1/;x;$!d;x;s/.//' file
```

What do these scripts do? Get a list like this

```
Chi Allegati N.22021.htm
Casabella Marzo 2021.pdf
Casabella Febbraio 2021.pdf
Chi Allegati N.22021.pdf
```

after you have used the sed / awk scripts you will get this output

```
Casabella
Chi Allegati
```

Where then is the problem? Okay, now consider another list

```
(Ebook ITA Fumetti) Genius 021 Bersaglio A Gog.cbr
(Ebook ITA Fumetti) Genius 022 Poker Di Delitti.cbr

Corna Vissute - La moglie del ladro.cbz
Corna vissute - Nuova serie 011 - Un'offerta irresistibile.cbr

Il piccolo sceriffo 20 (Dardo 1992-02) [c2c CapitanUltra].cbz
Il piccolo sceriffo 23 (Dardo 1992-05) [c2c dinofelix].cbr

Il mondo di Arkadi - Caza 01 - Gli occhi di Or'Fe (by aquila & Janesek).cbr
Il mondo di Arkadi - Caza 02 - Il grande esterno (by aquila & Janesek).cbr

Il segno di Zorro 21 (Edizioni del fanciullo 9-1976)(BYPico57).cbr
Il segno di Zorro Serie d'oro 07 - Il mistero della miniera (Edizioni del fanciullo 1975-10-01) [c2c Dinofelix].cbr

L'Uomo Mascherato 06 - Il ratto di diana (Nerbini 1938-09) [c2c Scaricatore17-Gitra].cbr
L'Uomo Mascherato 08 - Il ritorno di Diana (Nerbini 1940-10) [c2c Scaricatore17-Gitra].cbr

Le leggende di Batman 017 (Play Press 1997-12 c2c) By Samox.cbz
Le leggende di Batman 018 (Planeta 1998-01 c2c) [Play Press] By Samox.cbz
```

Unfortunately the script no longer works well. In fact, I would like to obtain this output (or something very close), but it is not possible

```
    Corna Vissute
    Genius
    Il mondo di Arkadi
    Il piccolo sceriffo
    Il segno di Zorro
    Il segno di Zorro Serie d'oro
    L'Uomo Mascherato
    Le leggende di Batman
```

Logic behind script:

1. Manipulate the line to contain only the fields required.
2. Append to the hold space.
3. Swap to the hold space, remove duplicate lines and swap back to the pattern space.
4. Delete all but the last line.
5. On the last line, swap to the hold space, remove the first newline and print the results.

**EDIT**: Add another example that script process incorrectly

I have this list

```
A porte chiuse 054 - Come la prima notte (Ediperiodici 1985-11) [noc2c Charles].cbr
A porte chiuse 097 - Il demone nella bottiglia (Ediperiodici 1989-06) [c2c noedit Charless].cbr
A Porte Chiuse 138-139 - Una viziosa incallita.cbr
A porte chiuse Special 13 - Il primo amore-Il viziaccio [228pag] (Ediperiodici 1986-03) [c2c Charles-Edit Gitra].cbr
A Porte Chiuse Special 020 [Fumetti.Erotici](1400~).cbz
```

but I will expect only this output

```
A porte chiuse
A porte chiuse special
```

But script return this

```
A Porte
A porte
```

EDIT: Another problem: I have

```
Il destino di Kakugo - vol 09 (MANGA ITA)(Scan & Edit by DDT)(DDT0580)(MQ jpg).cbr
Il mensile di Barbapap… N. 02 - [A.Mondadori] [1977-01] [ITA][c2c](no pagina centrale).cbz
```

but it return me

```
il
Il destino di Kakugo
Il mensile di Barbapap
```

or I have

```
Y L'Ultimo Uomo.-.Ragazze vol 07.-.(Magic Press)(c2c aquila).cbr
Y L'ultimo Uomo [08] Bambole Di Carta (Magic Press)(c2C Aquila).cbr
Yiu 01 - Inferno.cbr
Yiu 03 - Assassini (Scanlation, Ita, By Eleinad For Lc22Db).cbr
```

but it return me

```
Y
Y L'ultimo Uomo
Yiu
```

But I expect

```
Il destino di Kakugo
Il mensile di Barbapap
Y L'ultimo Uomo
Yiu
```

Comment: The second input file format varies wildly from the first simple example with no clear pattern unless I use my brain instead of a program (e.g. compare the `(Ebook ITA Fumetti) Genius` input lines vs the `30_Giorni_di_Notte_` input lines). How could we differentiate them ? In the wanted output there are potential problems: `Il mondo di Arkadi` is present two times, `Grandi eroi` is absent. One solution would be to take what is common between successive lines but even that won't give you exactly what you want.

Comment: @LudovicKuty yes, you're right, I remove from my example list `30_Giorni_di_Notte` and `Grandi eroi`. Could it be easier now? `Il mondo di Arkadi` It was present twice because I made a mistake in copying, sorry

Comment: The solutions above depend on the fusion of several parts - any error in a single part effects the final solution. From your comments above, identifying the elements of each line that can be matched for duplication is intrinsic to the final solution. Once this part of the solution is correct the rest will follow. Take a look again at the first item of your list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This modified `awk` script from my last answer should work for you:

```sh
awk '{sub(/^\([^)]+\) */, "")} match($0, /^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z\047]*( +[a-zA-Z\047]+)*/) {s = substr($0, 1, RLENGTH); unq[tolower(s)]=s} END {for (i in unq) print unq[i]}' file.txt

Il segno di Zorro Serie d'oro
L'Uomo Mascherato
Il mondo di Arkadi
Il piccolo sceriffo
Le leggende di Batman
Corna vissute
Il segno di Zorro
Genius
```

A more readable version:

```sh
awk '
{sub(/^\([^)]+\) */, "")}
match($0, /^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z\047]*( +[a-zA-Z\047]+)*/) {
   s = substr($0, 1, RLENGTH)
   unq[tolower(s)] = s
}
END {
   for (i in unq)
      print unq[i]
}' file.txt
```

Comment: Yes, thank you, very good but except one thing, look here please: https://pastebin.com/uiwLXUSp - if I have `Il destino di Kakugo - vol 09 (MA...`, `Il mensile di Barbapap… N. 02 - [A.` it return me `il` , 
`Il destino di Kakugo`, and
`Il mensile di Barbapap`. But I don't need to have also `il` in the list.

Comment: [Check this working demo](https://ideone.com/ILvjs8)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sed alternative:

```
sed -E 's/(^[^0-9\-\.\[\…\-]* ?).*/\1/' input | sort -u
```